# Compactification of a product of manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, compactifications

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. We make the assumption that $M$ can be viewed as the interior of a *compact manifold with boundary $\overline{M}$*. In practice, for an explicit manifold, any compactification could be chosen as long as it gives a compact manifold with boundary (without corners). The standard example is for $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\overline{M} = \overline{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is the *radial compactification* of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ is compactified into the n-dimensional unit ball where $\partial \overline{M} = \partial \overline{\mathbb{R}^n} = \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the “sphere at infinity”.

Now my question is about the compactification of the product $N := M\times \mathbb{R}$, where $M$ is the manifold introduced above (with $\overline{M}$ its fixed compactification). I would like to find a compactification of the same kind for $N$, in other words giving a compact manifold with boundary (again, without corners), using the compactification $\overline{M}$ of $M$ we have (since, afterwards, I assume some crucial information about $\overline{M}$ that I want to keep in order to describe $N$). When one tries the naive product $\overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ of these two manifolds with boundary, it gives a manifold with corners.

Is there a way to find a compactification of $N$ that explicitly involves $\overline{M}$ but still does not create any corners ?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** (january, one month after): I still have not found any detailed proof of that result. I have tried and read many things after Igor Khavkine and Shijie Gu answers but It didn’t work.
Would it be a direct way through the charts of $M$ to see this compactification, in local coordinates ? Fancy theorems seem too much since the product is just with the real line.

Comment: Do you want the compactification to be in some natural (elementary) way, a smooth manifold?  Most often compactifications are usually topological manifolds, and it takes some additional work to argue they are smooth.  In that regard, most arguments aren't much different that the manifold with corners argument you want to avoid.   For example the visual sphere compactification of hyperbolic space, in a sense it's more naturally interpreted as a topological manifold as diffeomorphisms extend to homeomorphisms.

Comment: I suppose that if $M$ were actually compact, then you would accept the compactification of $M \times \mathbb R \approx M \times (-1,+1)$ of the form $M \times [-1,+1]$?

Comment: @RyanBudney Sure, compactifications are usually topological manifolds indeed and in my case I want it to be smooth, that is the next issue

Comment: @LeeMosher In the case where $M$ is actually compact, since the assumption about $M$ being the interior of a compact manifold with boundary $\overline{M}$ holds, I think that I would not be interested in the compactification of $M\times \mathbb{R}$ into $M \times [-1,+1]$  as it is not dealing with $\overline{M}$

Comment: Re: **EDIT** From my end, you haven't really clarified what your difficulty is. Try to illustrate it using the example of $M\times \mathbb{R}$ with $M=(-1,+1)$. No fancy theorems needed here.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine In the case of M being the euclidean space we have coordinates and an explicit diffeomorphism (with the interior of the unit disk, in your example). The compactification wanted is the ball (in your case, dimension 2, the disk). I just do not know how to start and how to use the euclidean case when $M$ is actually an abstract manifold, in order to have an explicit compactification of the product $M\times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm sorry, you're going to do much better to explain where you get stuck. The general case is quite analogous to this special case.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Oh so I think I don’t even understand your method (not the explicit proof, but just why it works). On $M$ you have only local coordinates. We take $(U,\phi)$ a smooth chart of $M$ and the components functions $x^i  : U \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ of $\phi$ give some local coordinates on $U$ : $\phi(p) = (x^1(p), \dots, x^n(p))$. Now, how do you proceed ? How do you use the fact that $M$ can be compactified into $\overline{M}$ ?

Comment: Can you give me a hint? Sorry I can’t go further since I don’t even know what you proof consists in

Comment: @zarathustra Your hint has been to demonstratively work through the simple explicit example (realize the smooth boundary $S^1$ as the double of the manifold $[-1,1]$, compatible with an interior embedding). Unless I see something along those lines, this will by my last reply here.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Ok then if I don’t understand why that hint helps for passing to an abstract manifold, you won’t help more? Thanks anyway, but for me on $M$ abstract you can’t give an embedding as in the euclidean case since you don’t have coordinates and need to go through charts so I think my issues are legitimate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the quotient $C_M = \overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}} / \left\{\{x\} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}} : x \in \partial\overline{M}\right\}$ seems to do the job, where I mean that the points of the boundary cylinder $(\partial\overline{M}) \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are collapsed along the $\mathbb{R}$ dimension. The resulting boundary is $\partial C_M = \partial (\overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}) / \left\{\{x\} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}} : x \in \partial\overline{M}\right\} = (\overline{M} \sqcup -\overline{M}) / (\partial \overline{M} \sim \partial(-\overline{M}))$, which is a gluing of two copies of $\overline{M}$ reflected across their common boundary. This construction is known as the [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(manifold)) of the manifold $\overline{M}$. This gluing and quotienting has to be done a bit carefully to keep everything smooth.

Comment: Thank you very much. So do you actually think $C_M$ could be smooth ? I am looking at the quotient manifold theorem right now (and also if it is possible to extent a group action beyond the boundary) and it does not seem like an easy task indeed. Actually $(M,g)$ is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold, thus I have to see if the quotient inherit a pseudo-Riemannian structure (but it is probably not possible, I do not know)

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: Did you mean to write $\left\{ \{x\} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}\, \colon\, x \in \partial\overline{M} \right\}$?

Comment: @zarathustra: This answer, when specialized to the case that $M$ is already closed, produces $M \times \overline{\mathbb R} \approx M \times [-1,+1]$; that's sort of why I asked the question in my comment.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, of course. :facepalm: In a temporary bout of insanity, I convinced myself that the opposite order was correct.

Comment: @zarathustra: In the context of smooth manifolds, the quotient operation is at best a mental guide. What you really want to do is show that there is a smooth manifold with boundary, whose interior is diffeomorphic to $M\times \mathbb{R}$ in such a way that sequences in the interior escape to the boundary in the expected way. It is no more difficult than embedding $(-1,1)\times \mathbb{R}$ as the interior of a disc, while realizing that its boundary $S^1$ is the manifold double of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine : What does "sequences in the interior escape to the boundary in the expected way" mean mathematically ? And how does it show that the resulting manifold with boundary is smooth (maybe as $M \times \mathbb{R}$ being a  submanifold of the smooth manifold with boundary that I have to show the existence) ?

Comment: @zarathustra "What you really want to do is show that there is a (compact) manifold with boundary (say $C_M$), whose interior is diffeomorphic to $M\mathbb{R}$." No other conditions needed to have a compactification. The example of embedding $(-1,1)\times \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \overline{B^2}$ as the interior of a closed unit disc is not harder than in general. A possibly nice extra condition (because of the many choices!) is that the embedding extends continuously to $\overline{M}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}} \to C_M$ and realizes the topological quotient proposed in the answer.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Alright, thank you for helping me! There’s still one thing that bothers me : could this compact manifold with boundary (whose interior is diffeomorphic to $M \times \mathbb{R}$) be found explicitly (in this case it is the quotient $C_M$ in your answer) or I just have to show that it exists ? Because I don’t really see how to start to show this in practice.

Comment: @zarathustra How will you show that it exists without finding it explicitly? (rhetorical question) If you take the time to work out simplest example of the unit disc, where everything is quite explicit, I suspect that your doubts will dissipate.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine no sure because since $M$ is an abstract manifold, the only “explicit“ diffeomorphism would be between $M \times \mathbb{R}$ and the interior of your quotient $C_M$ (which is the interior or $\overline{M} \times \overline{\mathbb{R}}$), which is trivial to prove, so I’m left with showing that $C_M$ is a smooth compact manifold with boundary, again. But there is probably something I’m missing, as it seems obvious to you, I am going to think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "smoothing corners" or "rounding corners" technique introduced by John Milnor. See Differentiable structures, Mimeographed Notes, Princeton University, Princeton, N. J., 1961.
The idea goes like this: Let $M,N$ be manifolds with $\partial M \neq \partial N \neq \emptyset$. $M \times N$ is not a manifold since there are corners along $\partial M \times \partial N$. But we can give $(M \times N) - (\partial M \times \partial N)$ a differentiable structure. Using collars on $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ one can find a diffeomorphism $h$ from an open subset $U_1 \times U_2 \subset M \times N$ to $(\partial M \times (0,\infty)) \times (\partial N \times (0,\infty))$. Identify $(\partial M \times (0,\infty)) \times (\partial N \times (0,\infty))$ with $\partial M \times \partial N \times (0,\infty)^2$ and define a $\phi: \partial M \times \partial N \times (0,\infty)^2 \to \partial M \times \partial N \times \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$ by
$$\phi(x_1,x_2,r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta ) = (x_1, x_2, r\cos 2\theta, r\sin 2\theta)$$
The composition $\phi h$ induces a differentiable structure on $U_1 \times U_2$. Since $\phi h$ has differentiable overlap with charts on $(M \times N) - (\partial M \times \partial N)$, it gives a differentiable structure on $M \times N$.

[Craig Guilbault](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601229) explained how to complete a product of manifold $M$ with $\mathbb{R}$ in general, i.e., $M \times \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary. The proof is based on the proof of Siebenmann's collaring theorem. Using the "smooth corners" technique one can show that $M \times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold with boundary.

Comment: Thanks for you interesting answer. So using the "smoothing corners" technique, what explicitly is this compact manifold with boundary whose interior is diffeomorphic to $M \times \mathbb{R}$ ?